# Python Selenium HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=55538): Max retries exceeded with url:

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

hi i trying to make simple scrape using selenium this my code :

```py
def start_browser():
    try:
        service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
        opt.add_argument('log-level=3')
        opt.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        opt.add_argument('--silent')
        opt.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=opt)
        return browser
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error Happened while initialize driver ', str(e))


def login(Driver):
    try:
        Driver.get('https://www.example.com')
        email = Driver.find_element(By.ID, "email")
        email.send_keys(user_email)
        password = Driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
        password.send_keys(user_pass)
        

        login_button = Driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Login']")
        login_button.click()

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error Occurred While login:', str(e))
        print('Restarting...')
        Driver.quit()
        Driver = start_browser()
        login(Driver)
```

when Exception happens and trying to restart driver and login again i got this error:

```
Error Occurred While login: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=56474): 
Max retries exceeded with url: 
/session/f518907d0c501baad19fc85fb3994315/element 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
```

i use Python 3.9.4

Please any help.

i expect to restart and login again without any error